# How to diff two immutable objects

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Is there a way to diff objects in [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)?

Example:

```
let a = Immutable.fromJS({ a: 10 });

let b = Immutable.fromJS({ b: 10 });

let d = Immutable.diff(a, b);

// { a: 10 }
console.log(d.toJS());
```

This would be useful when testing to see how objects differ.

It doesn't have to show what's added/removed explicitly. I just want to see the properties that `a` differs from `b` so that I can make them equal again.

For example I do this:

```
console.log(a.toJS());
console.log(b.toJS());
```

and check the logs to see where a differs from b.

In other thought it might show both `added` and `removed` properties in the same output. The main point is to see where they are not equal.

so it could also be:

```
// { a: 10, b: 10 }
console.log(d.toJS());
```

or maybe:

```
// { added: { a: 10 }, removed: { b: 10 } }
// console.log(d.toJS());
```

Comment: What you mean by "diff" isn't clear from the code you've shown. In the usual meaning of "diff," the result of `diff(a, b)` would show that `b` has one key-value pair added (`{ b: 10 }`) and one removed (`{ a: 10 }`), but the result in your example shows only the latter. Can you describe with more detail the semantics you're looking for?

Comment: I made it clear now @Jordan

Comment: "I just want to see the properties that `a` differs from `b` so that I can make them equal again." What do you mean by "make them equal again"? If, say, `a` is `{ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }` and `b` is `{ bar: 2, baz: 99, qux: 4 }`, what is the output you would need to "make them equal"?

Comment: I mean in my test, I assert them to be equal, I will change my code to see that `state` is equal to `expected state`. @Jordan

Comment: *ahem* If, say, `a` is `{ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }` and `b` is `{ bar: 2, baz: 99, qux: 4 }`, what is the output you would need to "make them equal"?

Comment: @Jordan, if a is test subject, then I have to set a to `{ bar: 2, baz: 99, qux: 4}` so a is equal to b, in other words, test subject is equal to expected output.

Comment: If that's all you want, then just do `a = b`, or clone `b` with `Object.assign` or, say, `_.extend` from Underscore. But your question was about doing some kind of `diff`, so what is the output you want from `diff`?

Comment: I simplified this to make an example, but a is not something I control, it is the output of a function, b is what I expect the function will return. I will implement the function so the output looks like b. The comparison is to help me see the difference between the actual and expected output so I can implement the function correctly. @Jordan

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, [Immutable.is()](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is) compares two collections and tells you when they do not contain the same elements.

If that is not enough, use something like the npm package [deep-diff](https://github.com/flitbit/diff):

```
const diff = require('deep-diff').diff;
var differences = diff(a.toJS(), b.toJS());
console.log('differences:', differences);
```